# Robin input mask : iPhone shows pure numeric keyboard for decimal input

Tags: javascript, input-mask, jquery-inputmask

I have this MCVE:

```
<input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Price" id="price">

Inputmask.extendAliases({
     'SfdCurrency': {
         alias:                  "numeric", /* can be also decimal */
         digits:                 2,
         digitsOptional:         false,
         radixPoint:             ",",  /* can be also . */
});

$("[name='price']").inputmask({
     alias: 'SfdCurrency',
});
```

On iPhone [10 & 11 & 12] the pure numeric keyboard is shown [see the below screenshot] which doesn't have the comma which means that in order to enter digits after the comma the user has to click "*behind*" the comma. Android shows a keyboard with comma so any decimal number can be entered without an additional click after the comma sign.

[image]

**My question:**

What am I doing wrong because iPhone doesn't show a keyboard with comma for a decimal number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robin answered me in the Github issue section:

> Can you set the `inputmode` option to `decimal`.

Yes, this fixed the problem and the comma appears now also on the iPhone keyboard.

[image]